# Autocomplete with Table Alias in FROM clause

Tags: sql-server, intellisense, sql-server-2014

I have a query like

```
SELECT (***)
FROM longtablename as A;
```

Is there a way I can get typing "A.[" in the select clause to autocomplete to the columns of longtablename?

Comment: write `select * from tablename a` then go back and delete `*` and start typing `A.` and the intellisense should show you the column names.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any such intellisense present which will auto complete all the column names like `A.col1,A.col2,...,A.coln` but you actually don't need that. Either you can say

```
SELECT *
FROM longtablename as A;
```

(OR)

```
SELECT A.*
FROM longtablename as A;
```

Also, if you are using SSMS(SQL Server Management Studio) then you can use the [SSMS built-in intellisense feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms173743.aspx).

Comment: I don't think I worded my question well. I don't mean that I want it to iterate out all of the columns since as you said in your post just SELECT * will grab everything. My problem is that when I write queries it's inconsistent whether SSMS will autocomplete my fields. For example I'm within a join and want to type "A.[long column name]". Sometimes typing "A.[l" and tab will autocomplete, other times I must type the entire thing. I was looking for insight on why it works sometimes but not always.